# Sorting Photos using shell script

Tags: shell-script

The majority of my photo files have the following naming convention / format IMG_20131204_120000.JPG, showing date and time the photo was taken (iPhone/Apple naming convention).  However, not all my photos follow this naming convention.  With the help of this forum I developed the following script to categorize my photos into date directories:

```
cd '/photos/' 
for x in *.JPG *.jpg *.TIF *.tif *.PNG *.png *.BMP *.bmp *.GIF *.gif *.IMG *.img *.JPEG *.jpeg *.TIFF *.tiff; do
  d=$(date -r "$x" +%Y%m%d)" - Family Photos"
  t=$(expr substr "$x" 1 4)
  if [ "$t" == "IMG_" ]; then
    d=$(expr substr "$x" 5 8)" - Family Photos"
  fi
  mkdir -p "$d" >/dev/null 2>&1
  mv -- "$x" "$d/" >/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

PS. I use the IF statement to take the date from the File name itself if the filename is in the format IMG_20131204_120000.JPG as this date most accurately reflects the date the photo was actually taken, but if the file doesn't follow this naming convention I take the operating system date of when the file was last modified/created.

It works fine for the most part except where there are files that start with "IMG_" but then don't conform to the naming convention IMG_20131204_120000.JPG, for example a file called IMG_001.JPG or IMG_Photo1.  Is there a better way to structure the IF statement here so that it checks not only that the file starts with "IMG_" but also the next 8 characters are numbers / a date format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your if command to something like this:

```
if [[ "$t" =~ IMG_+[0-9]{8}[a-zA-Z]*$ ]]
```

The `=~` is a regular expression comparison operator which is introduced in bash version 3 and above.

By using this if statement you can catch names like `IMG_11111111alphabets.ext`.
You can play with it and customize it according to your needs.
For more information have a look at this: [Bash's regular expression](http://www.itworld.com/operating-systems/355273/unix-bashs-regular-expressions)

Comment: Unfortunately my system (Synology) doesn't support BASH only ASH.  I assume no easy way to do this under ASH shell?

Comment: @Wags I guess you can instead use what is called Shell Patterns in a case clause or something like that to achieve the same results in ASH. Take a look here (Shell Patterns): http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ash.htm

Answer (score 5):

I might go about this a little differently. ImageMagik can read the exif metadata from your image files. The format does not change.

```
identify -verbose example.jpg
```

returns (along with a lot of other information)

Properties:

date:create: 2013-11-07T04:55:55-06:00
date:modify: 2013-11-07T04:55:55-06:00

You could grep the create date and then parse it so you really wouldn't need to deal with the conditional statements or parse a strange file name at all